# Axios: Using baseUrl in a separate file causes problems with setting authentication token in axios request headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, axios, passport.js

I used to write the API Url inside the request like this:

```
export const getAllAdmins2 = () => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get("http://baseUrl:3083/api/admin/getAllAdmins")
    .then(retrievedAdmins => {
      console.log("getAllAdmins2");
      console.log(retrievedAdmins);
      // this.setState({
      //   usersInformation: retrievedAdmins.data
      // });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

But, this could be improved by setting the URL in a separate file :

> conf/api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://baseUrl:3083`
});
```

And so I changed the API request to this:

```
import API from "../conf/api";

export const getAllAdmins = () => dispatch => {
  API.get("api/admin/getAllAdmins")
    .then(retrievedAdmins => {
      console.log("retrievedAdmins insideAPI.get(api/admin/getAllAdmin)");
      console.log(retrievedAdmins);
      // this.setState({
      //   usersInformation: retrievedAdmins.data
      // });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

But, this caused a strange problem: **The code that was responsible for automatically setting the authentication token in each request no longer does its job.**  In the backend, the token is undefined:

```
 2020-02-28T17:49:41+0100 <notice> TokenServices.js:76 Object.HasValidToken Access Token:undefined
```

This is the code that's responsible for setting the **authentication header**:

> App.js

```
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);

  // Decode token and get user info and expiration
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Set User and is Authenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  // Now if you reload a page, if the user has already logged-in you will still have his info in he state

  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout User
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "/login";
  }
}
```

> utils/setAuthToken.js

```
// What we will do here will prevent us from manually making sure of having the token inside each relevant request
// If we're logged-in, we can call this function and it will always attach that authorization header
// TODO: Need to make sure that the token is stored inside x-access-token
import axios from "axios";

const setAuthToken = token => {
  console.log("setAuthToken is called");
  if (token) {
    // Apply to every request
    axios.defaults.headers.common = {
      // Authorization: token,
      //TODO: Not sure about this
      "x-access-token": token
    };
    console.log("token is: ");
    console.log(token);
    console.log("axios.defaults.headers.common: ");
    console.log(axios.defaults.headers.common);
  } else {
    // Delete the Auth header
    axios.defaults.headers.common = {
      //Authorization: token,
      "x-access-token": token
    };
  }
};
export default setAuthToken;
```

And this is the logging result of the setAuthToken:

```
setAuthToken.js:7 setAuthToken is called
setAuthToken.js:15 token is: 
setAuthToken.js:16 eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwibm9tIjoiYXZlbXBhY2UiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImF2ZW1wYWNlQGF2ZW1wYWNlLmNvbSIsIm1vdF9kZV9wYXNzZSI6IlUyRnNkR1ZrWDEvRGdCN3JUUjB1YTJvc1BIcm1hRkswN3pjTGd5aSsxcE09IiwibGFzdF9sb2dpbiI6bnVsbCwicm9sZSI6InN1cGVyX3VzZXIiLCJjcmVhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDIwLTAyLTI4VDA5OjQwOjE4LjM3MFoiLCJ1cGRhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDIwLTAyLTI4VDA5OjQwOjE4LjM3MFoiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODI5MDg0NjAsImV4cCI6MTU4MjkxMjA2MH0.8Btk4f0Bdw-pM2qGEbk0s5V-u3jBugIHYDKH8aoDzW8
setAuthToken.js:17 axios.defaults.headers.common: 
setAuthToken.js:18 {x-access-token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwib…A2MH0.8Btk4f0Bdw-pM2qGEbk0s5V-u3jBugIHYDKH8aoDzW8"}
```

It seems to be working. However, as I said, in the backend when I use **getAllAdmins** that uses the new implementation of the **axios url**, the **token** is `undefined` in the backend. But, when I use **getAllAdmins2** that uses a **direct** implementation of the **axios url**, the code is well received in the backend and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely due to the fact that the axios instance in `conf/api.js` is created before you set the token in `axios.defaults` so your instance will be unaffected. I.e. your order is:

- Create axios instance without token (done on include/comiple of api.js)
- Load token and set defaults

Since you essentially have a singleton axios instance, you can instead set it's defaults in place of the global defaults when the token is loaded, i.e.,

Before:

```
// This is setting the defaults used when creating instance and the global axios is used
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
...
```

After:

```
import API from "../conf/api";

...
// This will set the the defaults of your singleton instance
API.defaults.headers.common = {
...
```

---

The above should fix your issue with your current setup but an alternate option is to go back to using the global `axios` (e.g. `axios.get`) and instead set the base URL on it's defaults, i.e.:

```
// During app init:
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://your.base.url';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I would'be probably spent days, trying to solve this on my own. I am sorry for the late response because of the weekend.